# Images in iOS not working, but Android works HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do my first website using HTML and CSS (and Javascript for the hamburger menu) but I am having trouble with iOS (Chrome and Safari) and the website and Facebook Logo appearing.

The "AS" logo is a link to the landing page and the Facebook logo is a link to the facebook page.

It works absolutely fine on Android and desktop. Here is how it should look:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKreQ.jpg) This is Android.

And here is how its presenting on iOS:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jWn9.jpg)

I'll attach the HTML and CSS as well.

Any suggestions?

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Arcane Studios</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a id="arcaneLogo" href="index.html">Home</a>
            
            <ul class="navMenu">
                <li class="navItem"><a href="#aboutUs">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="navItem"><a href="#webDesign">Web Design</a></li>
                <li class="navItem"><a href="#softwareDev">Software Development</a></li>
                <li class="navItem"><a href="#digitalArt">Digital Art</a></li>
                <li class="navItem"><a href="#contactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            
            <div class="hamburger">
                <span class="hamburgerBar"></span>
                <span class="hamburgerBar"></span>
                <span class="hamburgerBar"></span>
            </div>

            <a id="facebookLogo" href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=61552713065536&mibextid=2JQ9oc">Facebook Logo</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section id="backgroundLanding" class="backgroundColour">
    </section>
```

And here is the relevant CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

header a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
}

header a:hover {
    color: rgb(185, 41, 214)
}

.navMenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 100px;
    transition: 0.7s ease;
} 


/* RESPONSIVE DESIGN, HAMBUGER MENU */
.hamburger {
    display: none;
}

.hamburgerBar {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: white;
}

#facebookLogo {
    background-image: url("images/facebookLogoTransl.png");
    background-size: 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    text-indent: -9999999999px;
}

#backgroundLanding {
    background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
}

.backgroundColour {
    background-color: black;
}
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1325px;
}

@media (max-width: 1321px) {
    .hamburger {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 30px;
        right: 30px;
    }
    .hamburger.active .hamburgerBar:nth-child(2){
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .hamburger.active .hamburgerBar:nth-child(1){
        transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);

    }
    .hamburger.active .hamburgerBar:nth-child(3){
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }

    .navMenu {
        display: none;
    }

    .navItem{
        margin-top: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        display: list-item;
    }
    
    .navMenu.active {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        right: -40px;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        text-align: right;
        transition: 0.3s; 
    }

    #facebookLogo {
    background-image: url("images/facebookLogoTransl.png");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    text-indent: -9999999999px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #backgroundLanding {
        background-image: url("images/backgroundPhone.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% -50px;

    }
    section {
        width: 100%;
        height: 900px;
    }
}


#arcaneLogo {
    background-image: url("images/logoTransl.png");
    background-size: 160px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    text-indent: -99999999px;
}
```

It all works fine for desktop too. I'm honestly really stuck so any advice or insight would be really appreciated!

I've tried using different operating systems and browsers and have found the problem lies purely with iOS, regardless of the browser type.

I've tried changing the display, margin, background-position, but nothing has worked.

Interestingly, other images, like the background image and also an image inserted below text works just fine on iOS.

Comment: Consider opening browser developer tools in iOS, there may be errors presented in the developer tools *Console* or *Network* tab that might indicate the problem.

Comment: Hi Wongjn, thanks for the advice! Do you know how you would look at that using an application like LambdaTest? I don't have access to a physical device.

Comment: Consider checking [their documentation](https://www.lambdatest.com/support/docs/developer-tools/#how-to-launch-developer-tools-on-mobile-browsers)

Comment: Thanks :) Sorry, I didn't even realise they would have documentation - I'm pretty new to this. 

Unfortunately, I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking at using the web development tools. I can see when I hover over the logo code it allocates an area on the screen. Following this trend, I changed the background colour of both logos to red/yellow  to see if that will populate on the screen in place of the image but it doesnt show at all on iOS, but shows on desktop.

Any thoughts? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Consider checking if there are errors presented in the developer tools *Console* or *Network* tabs that might indicate the problem

Comment: Nothing is showing up - any other suggestions? Do you know what might actually cause this as it seems to be a very specific issue surrounding iphones and ipad.